# How to count 0 orders?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to *find all employees (their names) and "Amount of orders" they made **(if any)**, sort them by name from A to Z, ensure all result columns have appropriate names.*

Here is my request:

```
select Employees.FirstName, count(Orders.OrderID) as "Amount of Orders"
from (Orders
inner join Employees
on Orders.EmployeeID=Employees.EmployeeID)
group by FirstName
having count(Orders.OrderID) >= 0;
```

But this request doesn't show one employee who made 0 orders.
What's the problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN. And remove HAVING.

Comment: No, try RIGHT JOIN! Or just change the order of Orders and Employees, because I'm not sure if MySQL has RIGHT JOIN or just LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy, oops, I didn't notice the table order. Anyway, I'd say switch tables and do a LEFT JOIN. (As it is much easier understanding `main table left join optional data`, instead of `optional data right join main table`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join from `Employees` to `Orders` and use left join instead of inner (or still from `Orders` to `Employees` as you've wrote it - but use right join in this case).

Also remove `having count(Orders.OrderID) >= 0;` condition which is redundant (I can't imagine negative orders count in your scenario):

```
select 
    Employees.FirstName, 
    count(Orders.OrderID) as "Amount of Orders"
from Employees
    left outer join Orders on Orders.EmployeeID=Employees.EmployeeID
group by Employees.FirstName
```